# django ajax request to take selected index

Tags: javascript, python, html, ajax, django

I use django AJAX request to take some data from my django form and return some information using this [manual](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/29/how-to-work-with-ajax-request-with-django.html) .
In this manual ajax script use change function to take data from select html chooses and work correct.

In my case I need to take data from selected index first any time to user visit this page and if change that option then need to work change function.but I don't know to do that

html :

```
<select id="id_username">
<option>user1</option>
<option>user2</option>
<option>user3</option>
<option>user4</option>
<option>user5</option> 
</select>
```

where is some is selected some times

ajax script using change function :

```
$("#id_username").change(function () {
  var id_user'= $("#id_username").val();
  var form = $(this).closest("form");
  $.ajax({
    url: form.attr("data-validate-username-url"),
    data: {'id_user': id_user},
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
     $('#info_user_1').text(data.user);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

javascript to take selected index :

```
var id_pel = $('#id_username').find(":selected").text();
console.log(id_pel);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please be more specific about your problem. By the way this code will not work because of selector id of `select` is **select_form** and in javascript you use `id_username` as your selector.

Comment: update my answer and change id (wrong copy paste).Look the change function work only if change select options,but I need to take selected value where the user visit page.how to send $('#id_username').find(":selected").text(); to views.py without need to change value